# Change starting date after I've signed an offer

Tags: start-date

Today something very coincidental and dramatic happened -- I scheduled a meeting with my boss to let him know that I will be quitting my job. When I showed up to the zoom meeting, I noticed that the HR person was also there and soon they announced that they could no longer hire me as the funding for my project is discontinued. Today is my last day of work and I will receive severance pay for a month.

As for my new role, I negotiated a late start date (three weeks from now) as I told the recruiter that I would need time to give a two weeks' notice and wrap up my work. Now I realize I can literally start working for them as soon as **tomorrow**.

Would it be okay for me to email the recruiter and inform her that I can start earlier  on next Monday or the Monday after next (which she offered but I postponed)?

Thank you so much for reading this!! It's like a movie script happening in real life.

Comment: That's the great news. Now, you should congratulate yourself for "Perfect Timing". You can get "double-pay" for 1 month, i.e. salaries coming from 2 companies for 1 month if the new company lets you start right away.  (Some other people may even think about the "severance pay" as the "Bonus" for going to the new company :-) -  Good planning on your part . :-)

Answer (score 7):

> Would it be okay for me to email the recruiter and inform her that I
> can start earlier on next Monday or the Monday after next (which she
> offered but I postponed)?

Don't email. Instead, call the recruiter, explain what happened and that you are excited to start sooner rather than later.

Most likely they will be excited, too.

This sort of thing happens all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I don't have their phone number, so I guess I will have to email them.

This is like a movie. I am still a bit shocked.

Answer (score 5):

Go for it - the worse that can happen is they'll say "no" and you get to kick back and relax for a month on your former employer's pay.

For what it's worth, something very similar happened to a former colleague of mine - he was actually working his notice when our former employer became insolvent. He phoned up his new employer, who he was due to start working for in a few weeks, and they were more than happy to take him on early.

(You may want to take advice on how your severance pay and your pay from your new company overlap; that is off-topic for this site though)

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph about overlapping pay, would you please explain a little more ? I thought that it would be as simple as if you get the extra salary or bonus for 1 month, and you report it on your income tax, and then pay the tax for it along with your other sources of income. Is there something else that the OP has to be aware of ?